# How i can get affinity mask with > 64 cores?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity` and `BOOL WINAPI GetProcessAffinityMask(...)` allows one to get an affinity mask for 64 logical cores. I have data center with 128 cores in 2 processor groups. How i can get affinity mask for each of them?

Comment: Research processor groups

Comment: read [Supporting Systems That Have More Than 64 Processors](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/d/f/adf1347d-08dc-41a4-9084-623b1194d4b2/morethan64proc.docx)